# Sorting a list by different type of list property

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have two lists of two different types.

List types are `ProductPackageRelation` and `Package`. I want to sort the list of `Package` by using list of `ProductPackageRelation` with `Sequence` property.

**Will be used for the sorting criteria:**

```
public class ProductPackageRelation : BaseDTO
{
    public int PackageID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }  // This is the sorting property
}
```

**Will sort:**

```
public class Package : BasePackage
{
    public int GuideID { get; set; }
}
```

**Here are my lists:**

```
var productPackageRelationList = _iPackageService.GetRelations();
var packageList = _iPackageService.GetPackages();


// Example ProductPackageRelationList
ID  ProductID   PackageID   Sequence
1      5            1         3
2      5            2         2
3      5            3         5
4      5            4         4
5      5            5         1



// Example PackageList
ID  GuideID
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     1
```

`packageList` variable will be sorted by `productPackageRelationList` variable's `Sequence` property.

How can it be sorted?

Comment: Its not really clear what you want to acheive but its likely you want to make use of IEqualityComparer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I try to sort packageList like packageList.OrderBy(p => SOME_CONDITION). Condition must contain productPackageRelationList of Sequence property. You can lookup the example Sequence data.

Comment: Given an item in `packageList`, how do you find its associated `Sequence`? That is fundamental to solving this. What is the relationship between items in `packageList` and items in `productPackageRelationList`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson ProductPackageRelation class has the PackageID. This PackageID property is actually "ID" property of Package class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join the lists and than order by `Sequence`:

```
var q = from p in packageList
        join r in productPackageRelationList on p.Id equals r.PackageID
        orderby r.Sequence
        select p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the lists and order it:

```
var q = (from p in packageList
        join r in productPackageRelationList on p.Id equals r.PackageID     
        select p).OrderBy( i => i.Sequence);
```

or OrderByDescending() if you want it upside down